# SQL SERVER 2012: Standard Deviation of rows per person

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, standard-deviation, stdev

I have table `ITEMS`:

```
Itemid, 
ItemName, 
OwnerID
```

Each row represents an item. An Owner can have multiple items. I want to calculate the standard deviation of items/rows per owner. Is it possible to calculate that using the `STDEV` built in function?

I tried that but it doesn't seem ok:

```
select STDEV(COUNT(*)) from dbo.ITEMS 
GROUP BY ITEMS.OwnerID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```
    SELECT STDEV(IQ.cnt) as SDofCounts from --'from' was missing
        (select ITEMS.OwnerID, COUNT(0) as cnt from dbo.ITEMS 
            GROUP BY ITEMS.OwnerID
        ) IQ
```

+++++++++++++++++

if you ran this to see some data

```
        select ITEMS.OwnerID, COUNT(0) as cnt, COUNT(0) * COUNT(0) as EXS   from dbo.ITEMS 
            GROUP BY ITEMS.OwnerID
```

then you could do

```
SELECT STDEV(IQ.cnt) as SDofCounts, 
       SUM(EXS) as SigmaEXsquare, 
       SUM(1.0 * cnt) / COUNT(0) as MU, 
       SUM(EXS) - (SUM(1.0 * cnt) / COUNT(0)) * (SUM(1.0 * cnt) / COUNT(0)) as Variance, 
       SQRT(SUM(EXS) - (SUM(1.0 * cnt) / COUNT(0)) * (SUM(1.0 * cnt) / COUNT(0))) AS SDcalc
        from
        (select ITEMS.OwnerID, COUNT(0) as cnt, COUNT(0) * COUNT(0) as EXS from dbo.ITEMS 
            GROUP BY ITEMS.OwnerID
        ) IQ
```

Comment: well at least I get a value :) but how I can validate it?

Comment: @aggicd pick 3 ownerIDs which you know their counts beforehand and filter them with a `WHERE`. Then see if the result is reasonable or not.

Comment: @EzLo (OwnerIDS, Number of items): (101,14),(104,5),(105,2),(106,1),(231,1) and the result I get is 5.50454357780915

Comment: Well I used this : https://www.calculator.net/standard-deviation-calculator.html?numberinputs=14%2C5%2C2%2C1%2C1&x=38&y=34 and it is correct! thank you!